# Velocity while pulling up a object using a rope

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

Suppose I had a body tied to a rope, and the rope attached to the axle of a motor which rotates I can pull up the object at a constant velocity. Using Newton's second law of motion I conclude that the tension in the rope is equal to mg.

My question is by what physical process is the motor able to achieve this. The force applied upward on the body is always(?) mg, how is the motor-rope arrangement then able to accelerate the body to the said constant velocity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin to lift the body the upward force of the motor (due to its torque) must be greater than $mg$ in order to accelerate the body. Once the body starts moving the upward force of the motor can be reduced to equal $mg$, for a net force of zero, and the body will continue to move upward at constant speed.

This is what happens with elevators. When the elevator starts to rise you can briefly feel upward pressure on your feet. That's because its upward force of the elevator motor is initially greater than the downward force of gravity on your body and the elevator. causing your body to accelerate. But once it starts moving the pressure stops. That's because it is upward force is decreased to equal the downward force of gravity on your body and the elevator, for a net force of zero and a constant velocity. The reduction of the elevator's upward force is due its control system (which I'm not familiar with.)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

At some point in the past the upward force on the body must have been larger than the downward force. That's it. There's two possibilities.

1. There is actually another downward force on the body or motor which was smaller at some point in the past so that T > mg but T = mg + (other force). Air resistance is a possibility here, but it could also a resistive force inside the motor.
2. The motor force was bigger in the past and now is smaller. Just because T = mg now doesn't mean that must have always been true. Maybe someone increased the turned up the throttle and then decreased it. When you drive a car you accelerate by pressing the throttle down then letting up when you reach the speed you want. Or maybe the motor provides a larger force at low speeds but naturally reduces the force it provides at higher speeds.

Comment: Yeah this makes sense, initially the motor could have provided some extra force due to the torque it creates. The body moving at a constant velocity is only a specific case I was thinking about, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you pull an object using the rope. You basically transfer the force applied at one end of the rope (in this case, by the motor) to the other end (to the body) through the rope, in the form of Tension. To answer your question the simplest way possible, I make the following assumptions :-

- Air resistance is ignored
- Variation of gravitational force with height is ignored
- No other forces act on the body apart from the earth's gravity and the rope's tension
- mass of rope is ignored
- The rope doesn't stretch and thus the entire force is transmitted without any losses.

Let's say initially the object is hanging freely at one end of a rope whose other end is connected to the axle of a motor (that can produce a torque and therefore a force on the rope). Now we would like to pull the object up. To do so, we must apply a force which is ever-so-slightly more than the force with which the block is being pulled down by gravity. The block which was initially at rest starts to accelerate upwards. The moment we let the force equal "mg", the acceleration ceases and the block continues to move upwards at a constant velocity which was gained till then.

Comment: yes I understand now, thanks!